# Debugging AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'?

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror

I'm having a problem to get my python scripts running in ArcMap.
I keep getting this message no matter what script i use.

> Executing: Script1
>   Start Time: Thu Dec 05 15:37:50 2013
>   Running script Script1...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Flori_000\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\ArcGIS\wk.py", line 11, in 
>       import arcpy
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from arcpy.toolbox import *
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 351, in 
>       from management import Graph, GraphTemplate
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 22, in 
>       import _management
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy_management.py", line 14, in 
>       import _graph
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy_graph.py", line 27, in 
>       import numpy
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 142, in 
>       import add_newdocs
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
>       from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib__init__.py", line 13, in 
>       from polynomial import *
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 11, in 
>       import numpy.core.numeric as NX
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
>
> Failed to execute (Script1).
>   Failed at Thu Dec 05 15:37:50 2013 (Elapsed Time: 0,40 seconds)

To make sure about my scripts i also converted a tool made with the ModelBuilder to PythonScript but the results were the same.

Does someone have any idea what this is all about?

Comment: what version of ArcMap are yo using? and what version of python do you have isntalled?

Comment: Can you run commands in your Python Window in ArcMap? Can you run even a basic script?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out myself.

There was an error in numpy. Just installed it again and now it works